# How to make a switch case for keyboard input in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, input, keyboard

I am playing around in C++ and currently have this "if" hell:

```
        if(GetKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000)
            {
                camRotX = camRotX-8;
            }
        if(GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000)
            {
                camRotX = camRotX+8;
            }
        if(GetKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
            {
                camZ = camZ+2;
            }
        if(GetKeyState('S') & 0x8000)
            {
                camZ = camZ-2;
            }
        if(GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000)
            {
                camX = camX-2;
            }
        if(GetKeyState('D') & 0x8000)
            {
                camX = camX+2;
            }
```

How do I make it so that it uses a switch case?

I tried making keyboard input for my game. Well, everything works correctly, but it looks ugly.

Comment: Since multiple options can be valid simultanously, I don't think a switch-case is a good fit for this.

Comment: The function only lets you test one key at once, so there's not really any way around multiple if statements. I guess you could do it with a loop that uses an array of keys to test and a lambda for each key to call if they're pressed.

Comment: @JonathanPotter a less generic solution is possible if all modified variables are of same type. The array would store a tuple of <key, reference, step>.

Comment: There's no requirement for you to pick an answer. If all contributions have been down-voted below zero, it's a good indication that neither one can be accepted.

Comment: Since you are querying multiple keys at once, consider using `GetKeyboardState()` instead, and then you can check the relevant array slots as needed